# Cannot create resource instance in Tomcat7

Tags: mysql, jndi, connection-pooling, tomcat7, server.xml

I'm trying to configure connection pool in Tomcat 7. Here is code:
part of server.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />


<Resource  
name="jdbc/testDataSource"                                  
auth="Container"                                            
type="javax.sql.DataSource"                                   
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"                      
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/delta_server"                
username="test" password="test"                              
validationQuery="select count (*) from session_contexts"              
/>
```

web.xml configuration:

```
<resource-ref> 
    <description> 
        Sample JNDI DataSource resource reference 
    </description> 
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/testDataSource</res-ref-name>                   
    <res-type>java.sql.DatSource</res-type>                           
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>                                     
</resource-ref>
```

and access from jsp page:

```
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        conn = (Connection)  envContext.lookup("jdbc/testDataSource");
```

But unfortunately I get exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:146)
javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:826)
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:145)
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:814)
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:91)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration looks pretty much OK (except for some typos in your `web.xml` file; the `<res-type>java.sql.DatSource</res-type>` should be `<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>`).

But the problem I think is the fact that you are declaring the database resource inside the `server.xml` file.

Normally the application resources should be declared in the `context.xml` file of the application and only be declared in `server.xml` if they are shared between applications. So my suggestion is to declare the `jdbc/testDataSource` resource in your `context.xml` file. That should be **one way to make it work**.

If you must absolutely have a global resource then in your `context.xml` file [you must add a resource link to it or it won't be visible by default](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html).

> This context is distinct from the per-web-application JNDI contexts described in the JNDI Resources HOW-TO. The resources defined in this element are not visible in the per-web-application contexts unless you explicitly link them with <ResourceLink> elements.

So the **second way to make it work** is to leave the resource declared in `server.xml` but then add something like this in your `context.xml` file:

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/testDataSource" 
              name="jdbc/testDataSource" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```